# Changing flash mode with a custom camera overlay

Tags: ios, flash, button, camera, overlay

I am using the UIImagePickerController with a custom camera overlay view and wish to add a custom button to toggle the flash mode between auto, on, and off. Here is the method the button calls:

```
- (void)didTapFlash:(id)sender
{
    if (self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto)
    {
        [imagePickerController setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn];
        [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashIconOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
        [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashIconOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashIconAuto.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

The problem is this doesn't work. The value of self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode never changes once the controller is presented. The flash value can be changed before it is presented but, once it is, it will always return a value of 0 (Auto). The strange part is, even though the value doesn't change, the flash behaves as if it does so if I change the above code to:

```
- (void)didTapFlash:(id)sender
{
    if (flashButton.tag == 0)
    {
        [imagePickerController setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn];
        self.flashButton.tag = 1;
        [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashIconOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (flashButton.tag == 1)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
        self.flashButton.tag = -1;
        [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashIconOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (flashButton.tag == -1)
    {
        self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        self.flashButton.tag = 0;
        [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashIconAuto.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected. (the flashButton.tag is just storing the flash value)

Does anyone know what is happening here? Why does the value of cameraFlashMode always 0 (both in NSLog statements and when checked directly through the debugger) even though the flash is behaving as though it is set properly?

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: If you use the code from the second segment of the question, the flash will work as expected, but new value is not updated on imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode so it's value has to be stored elsewhere (in the above code, I stored it on the tag). I still don't know the reason for why it works. I suppose CameraFlashMode just passes the new value on to a private property and is reset.

Comment: I think iOS 7.1 has bug. That's the thing for that issue. I previously check it's with iOS 7.0 and worked perfectly. But not work on with iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in latest iOS version,

you'll notice that it will work with enabling the flag of

```
 self.picker.showsCameraControls = true
```

but it shows the native camera control to your overlayview, so i hacked it with this code:

```
 self.picker.showsCameraControls = true
 self.picker.cameraFlashMode = .On
 self.picker.showsCameraControls = false
```

It is fast enough to not disturb user with the showing and hiding controls.
It Worked for me and i'm sure it will work in your case too!